# Difference between slicing vs indexing when index position is unknown

Tags: python, python-3.x

When an index position is unknown, is it better to use slicing rather than indexing as indexing returns out of range error?

```
from random import randint

__index__ = randint(0, 100)
print(__index__)

key = "Some random string which comes on our way and we don't find the length"

''' Slicing is better when unknown length of a string?''' 
x = key[__index__:__index__+1]
if x is '':
    print("No value in slicing")
else:
    print("Sliced value %s" % (x))

''' Indexing runs into IndexError: string index out of range when out of range'''
x = key[__index__]
if x is None:
    print("No value in indexing")
else:
    print("Indexed value %s" % (x))
```

When the random index is out of range, then it errors out in indexing. Is it better to use slicing in this case?

```
$ python main.py
98
No value in slicing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    x = key[__index__]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: It depends on your purpose. I would suggest you use indexing within `try: ... except: ...` because indexing out of range is not an expected operation. Slicing will silently handle the problem, which can be omitted when you don't pay attention.

Comment: It depends. Generally, errors are good when it's something you don't expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
from random import randint

index = randint(0, 100)

key = "Some random string which comes on our way and we don't find the length"

try:
    print('Index value: {}'.format(key[index]))
except IndexError:
    print('No value found with index: {}'.format(index))
```

To answer your question, it is better to index a sequence of unknown length than to slice.

In your code, `key[__index__:__index__+1]` is the same as `key[__index__]` except that indexing raises an `IndexError` if the index was not found, whereas slicing would return an empty string(or tuple, or list etc) if the slice wasn't found. Regardless, it is better to handle the case where the exception is raised, and at that point, you know the index was not found. This would also avoid the unnecessary `if else` statements in your code.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When the index position is unknown, its preferable to use the slicing rather than indexing. Since, getting the value by Index may raise an IndexError if we try to retrieve the value which is out of range of an object, simultaneously if we use the slicing operator it would not raise any kind of error even if we try to retrieve the value which is out of bound.Slicing will simply return an empty object for any index not found.

```
>>>l=[1,2,3,4,5,5]
>>>l[6:]
>>>[]
```

as you can see even if the value for index 6 doesnt exist still it returns an empty object without raising any error.
For same example, if we do indexing it raises an error

```
>>>l[6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```